# async/await , unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

When I use async await function I get deprecationWarning: `unhandled promise rejections are deprecated`. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

```
export const publish = async (exchange, type, message) => {
        try {
            const connection = await amqplib.connect(connectionString)

            const channel = await connection.createChannel()

            channel.assertExchange(exchange, config.messageQueue.exchange.type, {durable: true})

            logger.silly(`publishing message to ${exchange}`)

            channel.publish(exchange, '', type.encode(message).finish())
        }
        catch (e) {
            logger.warn(`error while publishing message, ${e}`)

            throw e
        }
    }


    const startConsuming = async () => {
        try {
            const {Get, Sort, Cleanup, ...elasticMessages} = expectedMessages

            await init(Object.keys(elasticMessages))

            amqpService(expectedMessages, onMessage)

            publish(`${config.messageQueue.exchange.prefix}Cleanup`, contracts.televic.historyLogging.Call, '')
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error('error while establishing connection to message bus', e)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" until you edit this and include some sort of actual question. So far you just made a bunch of statements with no question at all.

Comment: Do you want to solve the warning? Just add a .catch() to the async function

Comment: @HRK44 actually how to fix warnings

Comment: @StefanOctavian that's not necessarily the right thing to do. Some errors should not be caught. This needs case by case 
analysis.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Of course. I just said that adding a catch() would (probably) solve the warning. I know it's not the best thing to do though

Comment: @StefanOctavian fair enough. It is what he asked for.

Comment: @StefanOctavian but I have already catch

Comment: @Palaniichuk Dmytro, I mean ```publish.catch(() => {...})```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a `await` in front of or a `.catch` after:

```
publish(`${config.messageQueue.exchange.prefix}Cleanup`, contracts.televic.historyLogging.Call, '')`
```

But `publish` is an `async` function, so this function does not thrown an error, but its returned Promise will be rejected with an error. So if `throw e` is called in the `catch` block then `publish` is rejected with that error and this rejection is not handled.

So the code has to look that way:

```
const startConsuming = async () => {
    try {
        const {Get, Sort, Cleanup, ...elasticMessages} = expectedMessages

        await init(Object.keys(elasticMessages))

        amqpService(expectedMessages, onMessage)

        await publish(`${config.messageQueue.exchange.prefix}Cleanup`, contracts.televic.historyLogging.Call, '')
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('error while establishing connection to message bus', e)
    }
}
```